# Mount WIN10 shared folder inside docker container

Tags: docker

I wrote a python app that use [eel](https://github.com/python-eel/Eel).

Then I built a docker image using a Dockerfile

```
# For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python
FROM python:3.10-slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Install pip requirements
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8200

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

# Creates a non-root user with an explicit UID and adds permission to access the /app folder
# For more info, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-configure-containers

RUN adduser -u 5678 --disabled-password --gecos "" appuser && chown -R appuser /app
USER appuser

CMD ["python", "main.py"]
```

After building the image, I launched the container with

```
docker run -p 8200:8200 `
-v ${PWD}:/app/data `
--name EEL `
eel_image
```

Up to here everything is ok and the container is working as aspected.

Now I need the app to reach some files that are on a mapped network drive, but I'm not able to mount the shared folder to container.

My pc is inside a company domain (e.g. mydomain), and I'm using **Docker Desktop 4.23.0**
The folder that I need to be reachable from container is *K:\master\documents*.
From my pc (host pc for container) I can reach the folder in several way:

- K:\master\documents
- \\dfs\dfs\master\documents
- \\y.y.y.y\dfs\master\documents (where y.y.y.y is the result of  `nslookup \\dfs`  command)

I tried several ways, without success:

1. bind-mount directly in the docker run command

   ```
    docker run -p 8200:8200
    -v ${PWD}:/app/data
    -v K:/master/documents:/app/master
    --name EEL
    eel_image
   ```

   receiveing the following message
   `docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/uC/dfs/dfs//master/documents': mkdir /host_mnt/uC: operation not permitted`,probably due to the UNC path.
2. changed the path format:

   ```
    docker run -p 8200:8200
    -v ${PWD}:/app/data
    -v //dfs/dfs/master/documents:/app/master
    --name EEL
    eel_image
   ```

   The container is up and running, and frontend is working as aspected. But I can't reach file
   in the folder //dfs/dfs.... The content in */app/data* is ok, and */app/master/* folder has
   been created, inside the container, but it's empty.
3. create a volume and then mount it

   ```
   docker volume create --driver local 
   --opt type=cifs 
   --opt device=//dfs/dfs/master/documents 
   --opt o=user=username,domain=mydomain,password=mypassword
   --name testVolume

   docker run -p 8200:8200
   -v ${PWD}:/app/data
   -v testVolume:/app/master
   --name EEL
   eel_image
   ```

   Result as point 2. Container running, folder created but empty

Inside the container I have

```
$cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

So the question is... Is possible to access that damn folder from the container?

Comment: A little update. I've just discovered that if I mount the root folder (K:\) I can navigate through sub-folders. The problem is that the final folder is empty, but I know (trough host machine) that it has a lot of files. All the files are **read only**. This could be the reason why I see no files?